# Getting Error : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad::alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, memory, error-handling, segmentation-fault, bad-alloc

Getting an error Getting Error : terminate called after throwing an instance of `std::bad_alloc` `what(): std::bad_alloc`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <inttypes.h>

using namespace std;

int64_t fibonacci(int64_t n,int64_t m) {
    int64_t *fibarray = new int64_t[n];
    for(int64_t i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(i<=1)
            fibarray[i]=i;
        else
            fibarray[i]=(fibarray[i-1]+fibarray[i-2])%1000;
    }
    int64_t rett = (fibarray[n-1]%m);
    delete []fibarray;
    return rett;
}

int main() {
    int64_t n=0,m=0;
    cin>>n>>m;
    cout<<fibonacci(n+1,m);
}
```

Why `std::bad_alloc` has been thrown in this case?

i am calculating it for 2816213588

Comment: how big is `n` ?

Comment: How big is `n`? It's probably big

Comment: Unrelated to the original question, but you don't need to store all n-1 previous Fibonacci numbers to calculate Fib(n).

Comment: Yup i can do it by recursion but it will take a lot more time...

Comment: It has nothing to do with recursion and recursion won't take more time than iteration. You still don't need array, you only need three values - `f[n]`, `f[n-1]` and `f[n-2]`. You don't need to store `f[0]`..`f[n-3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, it's likely a problem with *n* being too large.

try replacing

```
int64_t *fibarray = new int64_t[n];
```

with

```
int64_t *fibarray = new(nothrow) int64_t[n];
if (fibarray == nullptr) return -1; // now check for null
```

Check for null before even entering the loop. This is good practice especially since you expose the values of *n* and *m* to the user without any limits or checks for validity.

Comment: My program is being stuck.. i am not getting any error but it is stuck... I am running it for 2816213588

Comment: also with a number that large, you are going to experience some overflow especially trying to store it into another int64. For example, just adding the last 2 numbers alone from that sequence and you're already outside of the range of uint64!

You can change your return value to a double and/or limit that n value to something that is within your max range. I would recommend the latter.

Comment: As a side note, consider for a second how much memory is being used by that one fibarray. Let's assume you're running on hardware where an int64_t occupies 8 bytes of memory. 8 * 2816213588 = 22529708704 bytes. Thats about 21 GIGABYTES of ram for a single variable! Sometimes these things can't be avoided, but as already mentioned  by Paul, this isn't one of those cases. You only need to keep track of the previous 2 fib values to calculate the current one